# How to fetch a Wikipedia webpage with AJAX or fetch()

Tags: javascript, ajax, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to dynamically fetch a Wikipedia webpage in the browser in order to further process the XHTML with XSLTProcessor.

Unfortunately, this does not work because I can't get Wikipedia to send the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in the HTTP response.

I tried to include the "origin" parameter as it is stated on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS, but without success.

It is important to me to obtain the complete web page HTML as it is obtained by the browser when navigating to that page, so the MediaWiki API is out of the question for me.

This is what I have tried:

```
var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek?origin=https://my-own-page.com";

fetch(url).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Maybe give some more money to Jimmy Wales :) You cannot force the website to serve up headers it's not already configured to serve. You can, however, write your own server-side proxy to fetch the content.

Comment: Okay, so this is just not possible. I thought maybe I was doing something wrong. Yes, a server-side proxy or script could do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this does not work because I can't get Wikipedia to send the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in the HTTP response.

No, you can't. It is up to Wikipedia to decide if they want to explicitly grant permission to JavaScript running on other sites access to their pages.

Since this would allow users' personal information to leak (e.g. logged in Wikipedia pages display the user's username, which could be used to enhance a phishing attack), this is clearly something undesirable.

> ```
> var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek?origin=https://my-own-page.com";
> ```

`origin` is an HTTP request header, not a query string parameter, and is automatically included in cross origin XMLHttpRequest/fetch requests without you needing to do anything special.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. In the jQuery example on the MediaWiki page that I have linked in my question, they actually do send origin as a query string parameter of the GET request URL, don't they?

Comment: They do, which is bizarre, unnecessary, and somewhat error prone. (That documentation is for the API not the main site though, and it requires that the origin be white listed in the mediawiki configuration).